# Callbacks using multiple functions

Tags: javascript, callback

I was given the below javascript problem and had a few questions.  What does `pipe(foo,bar,baz)(1,2,3)` do?  Does it pass in 3 functions with 3 parameters?  I'm not clear as the the syntax of the expression.

Implement a function `pipe()` that takes several functions as arguments and returns a new function that will pass its argument to the first function, then pass the result to the second, then pass the result of the second to the third, and so on, finally returning the output of the last function. In other words, calling `pipe(foo, bar, baz)(1, 2, 3)` would be equivalent to calling `baz(bar(foo(1,2,3)))`

Comment: `pipe` accepts three functions as its parameters.  It returns a function which accepts three values as its parameters.  The result of that function should be equivalent to calling `baz(bar(foo(1,2,3)))`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc., and try to do the work**. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

`pipe(foo, bar, baz)(1, 2, 3)` does this :

1. it calls the pipe function with 3 parameters : foo, bar and baz. This function returns a value, here, probably a function.
2. it calls this function (the one returned by the pipe function) with 3 parameters : 1, 2 and 3.

The rest of the homework is up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis following a function invoke that function. If there are identifiers or literal values within the parenthesis (more than one separated with a comma), then those values are passed as inputs to the function. So, the first part of the expression:

```
pipe(foo, bar, baz)
```

Is simply a call to invoke `pipe` and, in this case, `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are references to 3 functions (not invocations of the functions, just references to them).

Now a function can return a value and that value can, itself, be a function. So, if that is the case and we "evaluate" the return value of `pipe`, it may turn out that invoking this:

```
pipe(foo, bar, baz);
```

results in something like this:

```
function(a, b, c) {
    // do something with a, b and c
}
```

In which case the remaining part of your original code, `(1, 2, 3)` would be used to invoke that returned function and pass `1, 2, 3` to it as input arguments.

Here's a working example:

```js
function foo(x, y, z){
  console.log(x, y, z);
}

function bar(){
   // Not relevant to question/solution
}

function baz(){
   // Not relevant to question/solution
}

// This function expects 3 functions as input
function pipe(funcA, funcB, funcC){
  // When this function is called, it returns another 
  // function...
  return function(num1, num2, num3){
    // And that function calls other functions, using the input
    // from pipe and passing it along to foo
    funcC(funcB(funcA(num1, num2, num3)));
  }
}

pipe(foo, bar, baz)(1, 2, 3);
```